# How do I avoid Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null throws at /jslibrary/1607407272232/sfdc/AuraAlohaFrameNavigator.js:150:109?

Tags: platform-bug, summer-21

How do I avoid the error?

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null throws at https://domain.visualforce.com/jslibrary/1607407272232/sfdc/AuraAlohaFrameNavigator.js:150:109

There is a bug in the Salesforce Javascript file AuraAlohaFrameNavigator at the line 150 in the minified version or at the line 3447 of pretty-printed version

```
, r = function(a) {
        a = a.target || a.srcElement;
        var b = null;
        if ("A" === a.tagName)
            b = a;
        else if ("SPAN" === a.tagName || "IMG" === a.tagName)
            a: {
                b = 5;
                do {
                    a = a.parentElement || a.parentNode;
                    if (!a)
                        break;
                    if ("A" === a.tagName) {
                        b = a;
                        break a
                    }
                    b -= 1
                } while (0 < b);
                b = null
            }
        return b
    }
```

When a custom event is created in a custom LWC component which is exposed in the Visualforce tab in Lightning Experience through Lightning Out, `target` and `srcElement` attributes are not populated but the function `r` in Salesforce Javascript file `AuraAlohaFrameNavigator` expects them to be populated.

Steps to reproduce.

Create `customInput` LWC with the following HTML

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input value={value} name={name} type={type} step={step} required={required} onclick={onClick}/>
    </div>
</template>
```

and the following JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomInput extends LightningElement {
    @api label;
    @api name;
    @api step;
    _value
    @api
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    set value(val) {
        this._value = val || '';
    } 

    @api required;
    @api vertical;
    @api type = 'text';

    onClick(event) {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click', {detail: {value: event.target.value}, target: event.target, srcElement: event.srcElement}));
    }

}
```

Create `testApp` LWC with the following HTML

```
<template>
    Test App
    <c-custom-input type="url" onclick={handleOnClick}></c-custom-input>
</template>
```

and the following JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
const URL_HTTPS = 'https://';
export default class TestApp extends LightningElement {
    handleOnClick(event) {
        if (!event.target.value) {
            event.target.value = URL_HTTPS;
        }
    }
}
```

Create `testAppDependency` Aura Dependency App with the following code

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
    <aura:dependency resource="c:testApp"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="c:customInput"/>
</aura:application>
```

Create LexOut Visualforce Component

```
<apex:component >
    <apex:attribute name="component" type="String" description="Component name" required="true"/>
    <apex:attribute name="dependencyApp" type="String" description="Dependency app name" required="true"/>

    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="host"/>
  
    <script>
        var myUserContext = "{!$User.UITheme}";
  
        $Lightning.use("{!dependencyApp}", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
            "{!component}",
            { userContext: myUserContext },
            "host",
            function(cmp) {
            });
        });
     </script>
</apex:component>
```

Create TestPage Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <c:LexOut component="c:testApp" dependencyApp="c:testAppDependency" />
</apex:page>
```

Create Test Page Visualforce tab with TestPage page

Open Test Page Visualforce tab in the Lightning Experience

Click on the input

Observe the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null throws at
> https://domain.visualforce.com/jslibrary/1607407272232/sfdc/AuraAlohaFrameNavigator.js:150:109

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have opened a case with Partner Salesforce Support on 6/17/2021 12:59 PM and had a very long discussion with Salesforce Support representative which initially claimed that this is WAD (Works as designed) but finally they have accepted this is an internal Salesforce platform bug and provided [a link to the known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001ziIaQAI) on 7/8/2021 8:30 PM.

Strange but the known issue doesn't mention the problem with Lightning out.

Anyway, there is a workaround to use `composed: true` and `bubbles: true` in the custom event definition.

```
onClick(event) {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click', {composed: true, bubbles: true, detail: {value: event.target.value}, target: event.target, srcElement: event.srcElement}));
}
```